# In yii how to send password reset link

Tags: yii, forgot-password

In yii i am creating forget password functionality.For this user enters email id.If this email id is correct then i want to retrieve securityQuestion id from database and display that question to user.if his answer is correct then password reset link will get send to user's email id. In controller i had made action as

```
 public function ActionForget{if(isset($_POST['email']))
      { $record=User::model()->find(array(
        'select'=>'primaryEmail',
        'condition'=>'PrimaryEmail=:email',
         'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email']))
             ); if($record===null) {
         $error = 'Email invalid';
         }  else {
          $mailer = Yii::createComponent('application.extensions.mailer.EMailer');
          $mailer->IsSMTP();
          $mailer->IsHTML(true);
          $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
          $mailer->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
          $mailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
          $mailer->Port = 465;
          $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
          $mailer->Username = "abc@shailani.com";
          $mailer->Password = "abc";
          $mailer->From = "xyz@shailani.com";
          $mailer->FromName = "Balaee.com";
          $mailer->AddAddress($record);
          $mailer->Subject = "welcome to Balaee";
          $mailer->IsHTML(true);
          $mailer->Body = "<h1>Thanks to showing interest </h1><br>click on link for                            other detail ".$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($mailer->Send()) {echo "Please check mail";}
else {echo "Fail to send your message!"; }}}
else{ $this->render('emailForm'); //show the view with the password field}}
```

I am having password.php as view file for entering primary email id and submit button

```
     <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
         'id'=>'email-form',
           'enableClientValidation'=>true,
            ));
          echo CHtml::textField('email');
          echo CHtml::submitButton('Send');
          $this->endWidget();
```

But after submiiting primary email id by user,no action takes place. So can please someone tell me what changes i need to do

Comment: Please debug your code by placing echo statements and check where the control break, then find the problem.

Comment: I am doing it now stepwise. If email id correct then i want to retrive that user's securityQuestionid from user table in order to display security question to him.I had created query as- if(isset($_POST['email']))
{$record=User1::model()->find(array(
'select'=>'primaryEmail',
'condition'=>'PrimaryEmail=:email',
'params'=>array(':email'=>$_POST['email'])) );
if(!$record===null)
{echo "email exists";
$id=User1::model()->findByAttributes(array('userId'=>$record->userId));$sqid=User1::model()->findByAttributes(array('securityQuestionId'=>$record->securityQusetionId));echo $sqid;}} bt not working

Comment: Posting again and again won't help mam, try to write some code. Thanks.

Comment: To start with, try the findByAttributes function instead of find, you only need to specify array('primaryEmail' => Yii::app()->request->getPost('email')) there. Also you might want to change your if to if ($record != NULL) instead. !$record results in a bool and a strict check against NULL will always fail

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the name of the controller method be `actionForgot` instead of `ActionForgot`. PHP is case sensitive, also when you render the page send the model with it like `this->render->('emailForm',$email)` where `$email` is your model name

Comment: PHP is not case sensitive when it comes to functions/methods.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I like the start, and here are some of the fixes to the existing code above.

However what was your plan once you successfully sent the e-mail; see the existing code gets you a url that looks like this http://yoursite.com/yourapp/user/forget  and that will bring you right back to the form in which you enter your email, thus creating a giant loop.

See the link should in fact create be validated and thus giving the user access to their user record.  You need some other function to validate and allow for the password change.

```
<code>

public function actionForget() {
        if(isset($_POST['email'])) { 
         $record=User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email' => Yii::app()->request->getPost('email'))); 
         if ($record != NULL) {
              $mailer = Yii::createComponent('application.extensions.mailer.EMailer');
              $mailer->IsSMTP();
              $mailer->IsHTML(true);
              $mailer->SMTPAuth = true;
              $mailer->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
              $mailer->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
              $mailer->Port = 465;
              $mailer->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
              $mailer->Username = "yourgmailacccount@gmail.com";
              $mailer->Password = "P@ssWord";
              $mailer->From = "yourfromemail@yourdomain.com";
              $mailer->FromName = "HQ-DEV-01";
              $mailer->AddAddress($_POST['email']);
              $mailer->Subject = "welcome to CES Document Site";
              $mailer->IsHTML(true);
              $mailer->Body = "<h1>Thanks, please</h1><br>
                          click on link for other detail
                          ".$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

                           if($mailer->Send()) {
                     echo "Please check your email";
                }
                 else {
                     echo "Fail to send your message!"; 
                }

         } else {
            echo 'Email invalid'; 
     }
         else {
         $this->render('password'); 
         Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "Email is not valid!");
        //echo 'Email invalid'; 
    }

    }
else{ $this->render('password'); //show the view with the password field}}
      Yii::app()->user->setFlash('info', "Enter a valid e-mail!");
}
```

}